# Typing indexed Objects in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a constant which I defined from the backend structure

```
const MY_COLUMNS = {
    ID: 'id',
    NAME:'name',
    STATUS:'status'
}
```

I use this constant to initialize my object

```
const OBJECT = {
    [MY_COLUMNS.ID]: '',
    [MY_COLUMNS.NAME]:'',
    [MY_COLUMNS.STATUS]: '',
    pictures: [],
}
```

Now when I'm trying to add typings in typescript

```
interface ObjectInterface {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    status: string;
    [key:string]: string;
}


const myState: ObjectInterface = {...OBJECT}
```

it returns error Type `'{ [x: string]: string | never[]; pictures: never[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ObjectInterface': id, name, status..etc`

How do I type this Object?

Comment: The straightforward part here is giving `MY_COLUMNS` a more specific type so that `OBJECT` has strongly typed keys, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/GNl4ON).  But what do you want `ObjectInterface` to be?  The `pictures` property of `OBJECT` is incompatible with the string index signature of `ObjectInterface` and I don't understand the use case enough to suggest which thing to fix.  I'd be happy to write up an answer if you can clear up what's going on.

Comment: OBJECT would represent an empty state which has values would be sent to API. In the object, the primitive values are field of a table. while picture is another array of number which would be sent to another table. And I've used [key:string]: string as a fix but it didnt work.

Comment: I have added in the link you provided [key:string]: string | number[] and i got no more errors. so it worked?